# Smtp authentification required

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, gmail

I have an asp.net mvc application, and I'd like to send an email :

```
 MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            var smtpClient = new  SmtpClient();
            {
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password");
                smtpClient.Timeout = 20000;
            }
            mailMessage.To.Add(model.Email);
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("support@team.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Modification de mot de passe";
            mailMessage.Body = "Vous avez modifié votre mot de passe de votre Compte ";
            mailMessage.Body += Environment.NewLine;
            mailMessage.Body += "le nouveau mot de passe est : ";
            mailMessage.Body += newPassword; 
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

I get this exception :

> La réponse du serveur était : 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

in last line of code.

I need to know what is the reason of this problem? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Because it's simply an authentication issue.

Comment: @Coulton it's also a code issue as he hasn't set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false.

Comment: @user1666620 Indeed, as stated in the duplicate question

Comment: it's a simple question that wouldn't exist if he would have used the search function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the SMTP client that you will not be using your windows credentials to access the SMTP, so add

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

**above** this line of code

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password");
```

Also, gmail doesn't allow impersonation, so

```
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("support@team.com");
```

will have no effect - the emails will still appear to be sent from the email account you are accessing.

Also, make sure that the setting "allow less-secure applications" is set on your gmail account, and that 2-factor authentication is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you SSL enabled on your account?

Depending on your Gmail account settings, you may get authentication errors within your app. If your Gmail account uses 2-Step-Verification, you should generate an App password to use for your mailer_password parameter. You should also ensure that you allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account.